# top 5 highest only specific rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this in my column A and column B is the number after the text.

```
Access rights   
Question    2
Total - Access rights   2
Adobe software  
Error   1
Total - Adobe software  1
Autorisaties    
Question    1
Total - Autorisaties    1
AX  
Question    13
Error   14
Total - AX  27
Backup  
Question    1
Total - Backup  1
Computer    
Question    4
Error   6
Total - Computer    10
```

Right now I have this formula:

`=INDEX($A$2:$A28;MATCH(1;INDEX(($B$2:$B$28=LARGE($B$2:$B$28;ROWS(D$1:D1)))*(COUNTIF(D$1:D1;$A$2:$A$28)=0););0))`

to get the largest value. So in this case the first line is Total AX.
And when I drag that formula down it says error because that is the 2nd largest number.

What I want is that it look looks at the total - value so in this case it should first by Total -AX and then Total -computer and then total access rights and than the rest because some of them are showing 1 as total

Comment: Hi, have you thought using conditional formatting?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Select the cells that contains the Total for each activity and use a conditional format, such as "Top 10" or 5, depending on how many you want to highlight.

Comment: The problem is next month their will come a new value next to the B column so maybe next month total access rights has the most. We wont want to do it manually selecting the cells wich have the most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you an idea:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(LARGE((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Total - ",$A$1:$A$10))*($B$1:$B$10)),ROW()),$B$1:$B$10,0))
```

Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down....

**EDIT**

In case you have duplicates, an helper column would be advisable IMO. Like so:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=LARGE((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Total - ",$A$1:$A$10))*($B$1:$B$10)),ROW())
```

Formula in `F1`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,SMALL(IF(E1=$B$1:$B$10,ROW($A$1:$A$10)-ROW($A$1)+1),COUNTIF($E$1:E1,E1)))
```

Both being array formulas entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thank you but when I do this I get an #Value error.

Comment: @klaas123, did you put it in as an array? Cause if you did this right there is absolutely no error when I you have the same data as my test ;). Array means you don't just press enter when you confirm the formula, you hold control + Shift and then press enter.

Comment: With your data it works only when I for example I make Test 6 and Test 10 the same values(which can happen) and drag down the formula it shows test 6 2 times instead of test 6 and then test 10

Comment: If you are looking for the dutch variant: `=INDEX($A$1:$A$10;VERGELIJKEN(GROOTSTE((ISGETAL(VIND.SPEC("Total - ";$A$1:$A$10))*($B$1:$B$10));RIJ());$B$1:$B$10;0))`. Notice the difference in seperator, semicolon vs comma

Comment: It works but the duplicate values also need to be in it so I made Test 6 19 and test 10 also 19. It that needs to show in E1 Test 6 and also in E2 test 6. It needs to be E1 test 6 or test 10 and E2 the other one.

Comment: In that case a helper column would be advisable, I'll update the answer.